# Return type based on the type that's returned in typescript

Tags: typescript, return

I'm trying to solve this little exercise from a school assignment and I just can't get my head around it.

I have this:

```
const settings = {
    path: 'c:/somewhere',
    minimum: 1,
    verbose: true
}

export function setting(key: keyof typeof settings): ???{
    
    return settings[key]
}
```

What I need to do is let the return type be the type of the field that's selected with 'key'. I tried using generics but I'm too inexperienced to wrap my head around it. I looked up tons of other people asking about it but perhaps I'm just too tired.

Could anyone give me some advice? I'm not allowed to change the body of the function, only specify/add/change the typing of the function.

Comment: `export function setting<T extends keyof typeof settings>(key: T): (typeof settings)[T] {`

Comment: @zerkms that worked perfectly, thank you so much!